# how to query AWS Athena where data is JsonSerDe format?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I need to query some data in AWS Athena. The source data in s3 is compressed json .gz format. It was created with the parameter

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
```

If I just do 'select *' there's one column like this:

```
{userid={s=my_email@gmail.com}, timestamp=2022-07-21 10:00:00, appID={s=greatApp}, etc.}
```

I am trying to query like this:

```
with dataset as
(select * FROM "default"."my_table" limit 10)
select json_extract(item, '$.userid') as user
from dataset;
```

But getting an error:

```
Expected: json_extract(varchar(x), JsonPath) , json_extract(json, JsonPath)
```

Is there something wrong with my query?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. You just use "dot" notation to access the keys:

```
select item.userid.s as user, 
    item.timestamp,
    item.appID.s as appID
from my_table limit 10;
```